# I am writing a Tkinter GUI which will read a value from a Hardware and write it to CSV file using pandas but I am getting an error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

```
#Storing data to CSV file
names=[]
c=Id.get()
names.append(c)
val=[]
d=hb.get()
val.append(d)
newd=dict(zip(names,val))
p.DataFrame(newd)
p.to_csv("Report.csv")
```

> This is my code I wanted to read data from a hardware and write that data to a CSV file using above code but, unfortunately it is not working plz help!

Comment: this is not a standalone sample,  what are `Id` and `hb` and what do the `get()` methods return?  Strings?

Comment: You say  you are getting an error but you haven't told us the error. Please [edit] your question to include the error.

Answer (score 0):

- defined a class **Id** to prototype your code
- it's standard to `import pandas as pd` not **p**
- your `DataFrame` constructor is an invalid structure,  a list of dict is valid
- all the code can be simplified to one line

```
import pandas as pd
class Id:
    @staticmethod
    def get():
        return "hello"
hb = Id
    
#Storing data to CSV file
## unneeded complexity start
names=[]
c=Id.get()
names.append(c)
val=[]
d=hb.get()
val.append(d)
newd=dict(zip(names,val))
# pandas constructor needs to be a valid structure
# assuming, "names" are column names and "val" values
pd.DataFrame([newd]).to_csv("Report.csv")
## unneeded complexity end

# simplify code
pd.DataFrame([{Id.get():hb.get()}]).to_csv("Report.csv")
```

Comment: Rob Raymond sir thanks actually I started Pandas recently and I am not that good at Pandas. Thanks once again sir!